# Script code not pulling Json data into div

Tags: javascript, json

so I have a javascript file that pulls contents from a json file and uses the data to fill a div on the index page named 'content', this is my javascript file but currently my index page is blank:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("content");

function init() {
loadJSON(function(e) {
    for (var t = JSON.parse(e), n = Object.keys(t.film).length, a = 0; a < n; a++) {
        var i = document.createElement("img");
        i.src = t.films[a].url, i.setAttribute("class", "filmimage"), wrapper.appendChild(i)
    }
})
}

 function loadJSON(e) {
 var t = new XMLHttpRequest;
t.overrideMimeType("application/json"), 
t.open("GET", "dist/json/data.json", !0), 
t.onreadystatechange = function() {
    4 === t.readyState && "200" === t.status && e(t.responseText)
 }, t.send(null)
 }
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
init()
});
```

[Download files of index, and other files can be found here](https://files.fm/u/5jm8n5qt)

Comment: Code seems okay, Can you please share some url where i can check that

Comment: @RobinB I only have it on local currently, is there a way I can send you the files or something?

Comment: Please zip file and share link here. I will share solution

Comment: Some suggestions, also regarding your convoluted coding style: https://pastebin.com/AY7fU7sF

Comment: @RobinB I've added a download link in the question, let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: For one, you need `200` instead of `"200"` if you're going to use `===` And you have `Object.keys(t.film)` but it should be `t.films`

Comment: I have post the new js in my answer.. there were two mistake one is remove " from 200 and another is film should be films

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your js file

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("content");

function init() {

    loadJSON(function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        for (var t = JSON.parse(e), n = Object.keys(t.films).length, a = 0; a < n; a++) {
            var i = document.createElement("img");
            i.src = t.films[a].url, i.setAttribute("class", "filmimage"), wrapper.appendChild(i)
        }
    });
}

function loadJSON(e) {
    var t = new XMLHttpRequest;
    t.overrideMimeType("application/json"), 
    t.open("GET", "dist/json/data.json", !0), 
    t.onreadystatechange = function() {
        4 === t.readyState && "200" == t.status && e(t.responseText)
    }, t.send(null)
 }


init();
```

Comment: The `Object.keys()` part is nonsense; `t.films` is an Array. Not your fault, but should be fixed anyway.

Comment: Ah this works thank you! Sorry my bad, I missed that part but again thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script, fixed, using `fetch()` instead of the obsolete `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("content");

function init() {
  fetch("dist/json/data.json").then(r => r.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.films.forEach(film => {
        var i = document.createElement("img");
        i.src = film.url;
        i.classList.add("filmimage");  // use CSS instead: #content img { ... }
        wrapper.appendChild(i)
      });
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```